# Classify text from a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe which is built from parsing raw text files into a list and then into the dataframe.

```
                                                                       Content
0                                                                     POLITICS
1               A Renewed Push in New York to Open Police Disciplinary Records
2                                                                  11:59 PM ET
3                                                                  CORRECTIONS
4                                                 Corrections & Amplifications
5                                                                  11:25 PM ET
6                                                                     NEW YORK
7   New York City to Have Curfew as Protests Over George Floyds Death Continue
8                                                                  10:20 PM ET
9                                                                         U.S.
10              Fresh Data Shows Heavy Coronavirus Death Toll in Nursing Homes
11                                                                  8:49 PM ET
12                                                                    BUSINESS
13    Reports of Violence Against Journalists Mount as U.S. Protests Intensify
14                                                                  8:05 PM ET
15                                                           MEDIA & MARKETING
16                      Music Labels Suspend Work in Support of Demonstrations
17                                                                  7:32 PM ET
18                                                            REVIEW & OUTLOOK
19                                                     Dont Call in the Troops
20                                                                  7:31 PM ET
21                                                                    NEW YORK
22                       Manhattan Stores Prepare for Another Night of Looting
23                                                                  7:31 PM ET
24                                                                     OPINION
25                                                 Dave Patrick Underwood, RIP
26                                                                  7:30 PM ET
27                                                            REVIEW & OUTLOOK
28                                       Courts Arent Financial Clearinghouses
29                                                                  7:27 PM ET
```

I would like to know if there is any way to split this column into 3 columns like these `['Topic','Headline','Time']`. Each row contains data for one of these columns. I would like to split them without doing any manual work. I think the entire dataframe does not follow the pattern of Topic, Headline, Time. At some point the pattern changes since the raw data was created by hand. So, if the rows could be classified based on regex or something that allows to maintain the time series structure; that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Addresses: *At some point the pattern changes*

- Using a list comprehension, find data for each header

  - The order of list creation matters, `time`, `top`, and then `head`.
  - The `time` pattern must be consistent with 2 character time zones, contains `AM` or `PM`, and `hh:mm` or `h:mm`.
  - The `top` pattern should maintain the pattern of all uppercase characters and not in `time`.
  - `head` is anything not in `time` or `top`.
- The following implementation uses fairly simple matching

  - There are undoubtedly more sophisticated regular expressions that could be applied.

```py
import re
import pandas

# find components for each list
time = [v for v in cont if (len(v) in [10, 11]) & (':' in v)]  # the time pattern must be consistent
top = [v for v in cont if ''.join(re.findall('\w', v)).isupper() & (v not in time)]  # topics characters must be all uppercase
head = [v for v in cont if v not in time + top]  # anything not in the other two lists

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': time, 'Topic': top, 'Headline': head})
```

### Addresses: Column maintains a continuous pattern

- I'd convert the column to a list and use string slicing
- This only works for a continuous pattern

  - It doesn't address *At some point the pattern changes since the raw data was created by hand*.

```py
# given your dataframe as df

# create a new dataframe with 3 columns
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cat', 'desc', 'time'])

# select data for columns
df_new.cat = df.Content.tolist()[0::3]
df_new.desc = df.Content.tolist()[1::3]
df_new.time = df.Content.tolist()[2::3]

# display(df_new)
                 cat                                                                        desc         time
0           POLITICS              A Renewed Push in New York to Open Police Disciplinary Records  11:59 PM ET
1        CORRECTIONS                                                Corrections & Amplifications  11:25 PM ET
2           NEW YORK  New York City to Have Curfew as Protests Over George Floyds Death Continue  10:20 PM ET
3               U.S.              Fresh Data Shows Heavy Coronavirus Death Toll in Nursing Homes   8:49 PM ET
4           BUSINESS    Reports of Violence Against Journalists Mount as U.S. Protests Intensify   8:05 PM ET
5  MEDIA & MARKETING                      Music Labels Suspend Work in Support of Demonstrations   7:32 PM ET
6   REVIEW & OUTLOOK                                                     Dont Call in the Troops   7:31 PM ET
7           NEW YORK                       Manhattan Stores Prepare for Another Night of Looting   7:31 PM ET
8            OPINION                                                 Dave Patrick Underwood, RIP   7:30 PM ET
9   REVIEW & OUTLOOK                                       Courts Arent Financial Clearinghouses   7:27 PM ET
```

#### Using a loop

```py
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

for i, col in enumerate(['Topic','Headline','Time']):
    df_new[col] = df.Content.tolist()[i::3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The above ones are awesome solutions. You should use one of them. I also wanted to give you another option to consider using skiprows.

Also, I used read_table instead of read_csv. Your input file has commas in the file. If you use csv, it will truncate the data and you will not get the full data.

The way to use this option will be:

```
import pandas as pd

#you can use skiprows option to skip the rows and read only specific lines like these
df1 = pd.read_table('xyz.txt', header = None, names=['Topic'],   skiprows=lambda x: (x%3 == 1 or x%3 == 2))
df2 = pd.read_table('xyz.txt', header = None, names=['Headline'],skiprows=lambda x: (x%3 == 0 or x%3 == 2))
df3 = pd.read_table('xyz.txt', header = None, names=['Time'],    skiprows=lambda x: (x%3 == 0 or x%3 == 1))

#now that you  have all 3 dataframes
#you can concatenate them to create your final dataframe 
df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)

print (df4)
```

**Output will be as follows**

```
               Topic                                           Headline         Time
0           POLITICS  A Renewed Push in New York to Open Police Disc...  11:59 PM ET
1        CORRECTIONS                       Corrections & Amplifications  11:25 PM ET
2           NEW YORK  New York City to Have Curfew as Protests Over ...  10:20 PM ET
3               U.S.  Fresh Data Shows Heavy Coronavirus Death Toll ...   8:49 PM ET
4           BUSINESS  Reports of Violence Against Journalists Mount ...   8:05 PM ET
5  MEDIA & MARKETING  Music Labels Suspend Work in Support of Demons...   7:32 PM ET
6   REVIEW & OUTLOOK                            Dont Call in the Troops   7:31 PM ET
7           NEW YORK  Manhattan Stores Prepare for Another Night of ...   7:31 PM ET
8            OPINION                        Dave Patrick Underwood, RIP   7:30 PM ET
9   REVIEW & OUTLOOK              Courts Arent Financial Clearinghouses   7:27 PM ET
```